# Java async problems

Tags: java

So my code works just the way I want it the only issue I'm having is this.. Basically I am having a main class which controls gates on a railroad track, when a train is approaching or crossing the track from either 1 of two tracks the gates should close. The only issue I'm having is the statements for when a gate opens or closes spam like 3-5 times everytime it does something so if the gate is closing it will go..

```
GATE: Closing
GATE: Closing
GATE: Closing
GATE: Closing
GATE: Closing
GATE: Closed
```

I'm wondering why this is occuring, here is my code for the Gate class and Main class

```
public class Gate {

    private boolean isClosed = false;
    private boolean closing = false;
    private boolean opening = false;

    public Gate(){

    }

    public void close(){
        if(!(isClosing() == true)){
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try { 
                        setClosing(true);
                        setOpening(false);
                        System.out.println("GATE: Closing");
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                        System.out.println("GATE: Closed");
                        setClosed(true);
                        setClosing(false);
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(task, "closeThread").start(); 
        }
    }

    public void open(){
        if(!(isOpening() == true)){
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try { 
                        setOpening(true);
                        System.out.println("GATE: Opening");
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                        setOpening(false);
                        if(closing == false){
                            setClosed(false);
                            System.out.println("GATE: Opened");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(task, "openThread").start(); 
        }
    }

    public boolean isClosed(){
        return isClosed;
    }

    public boolean isClosing(){
        return closing;
    }

    public boolean isOpening(){
        return opening;
    }

    public synchronized void setClosing(boolean t){
        closing = t;
    }

    public synchronized void setOpening(boolean t){
        opening = t;
    }

    public synchronized void setClosed(boolean t){
        isClosed = t;
    }
}


public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args){
                    Track t1 = new Track("Track 1");
                    Track t2 = new Track("Track 2");
                    Gate g = new Gate();
                    t1.simulateTrack();
                    t2.simulateTrack();
                    do{
                        System.out.print("");
                        if((t1.isApproaching() || t1.isCrossing()) || (t2.isApproaching() || t2.isCrossing())){
                            if(!g.isClosed() && !g.isClosing()){
                                g.close();
                            }
                        }else if(g.isClosed() && !g.isOpening()){
                            g.open();
                        }
                    }while((t1.isSimulating() || t2.isSimulating()));


    }
}
```

Also the code for Track

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Track {

    private static final SecureRandom gen = new SecureRandom() ;
    private boolean approaching = false;
    private boolean atCrossing = false;
    private boolean simulating = false;
    private String trackName = "";

    public Track(String n){
        trackName = n;
    }

    public void simulateTrack(){
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    setSimulating(true);
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                        Thread.sleep((gen.nextInt(5000) + 2500));
                        setApproaching(true);
                        System.out.println(trackName + ": Train is now approaching.");
                        Thread.sleep((gen.nextInt(5000) + 3500));
                        setCrossing(true);
                        setApproaching(false);
                        System.out.println(trackName + ": Train is now crossing.");
                        Thread.sleep((gen.nextInt(1000) + 1000));
                        setCrossing(false);
                        System.out.println(trackName + ": Train has left.");
                    }
                    setSimulating(false);
                } catch (Exception ex) { 

                } 
            } 
        }; 
        new Thread(task, "simulationThread").start(); 
    }

    public boolean isApproaching(){
        return approaching;
    }

    public boolean isCrossing(){
        return atCrossing;
    }

    public boolean isSimulating(){
        return simulating;
    }

    public synchronized void setSimulating(boolean t){
        simulating = t;
    }
    public synchronized void setApproaching(boolean t){
        approaching = t;
    }

    public synchronized void setCrossing(boolean t){
        atCrossing = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code for `Track`?

Comment: I'll post it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea:
By shooting the `close()` logic on a background thread you lose the atomicity. The `main`'s `do` loop can go around 5 times before it gives up the control of the main thread and one of the "closeThread"s start executing. Don't you see multiple "GATE: Closed"s as well?

Try this (not tested, sorry):

```
public synchronized void close() { // added synchornized
    if (!isClosing()) { // read: "if not closing"
        setClosing(true); // set closing so next time close() is called it is a no op
        setOpening(false); // close other loopholes so the state is correct
        System.out.println("GATE: Closing");
        // we're in closing state now, because the close method is almost finished
        // start the actual closing sequence
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                    System.out.println("GATE: Closed");
                    setClosed(true);
                    setClosing(false);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(task, "closeThread").start();
    }
}
```

You'll need to modify `open()` the same way, so that the invariants are always kept. Checking and setting the `closing` and `opening` flags are mutually exclusive, that's what you get by placing `synchronized` on both of them.